# How to share Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles sections to other users?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I have an apple store account and I want to share my account details with my developer so he can able to build and test applications within his iPhone.

This is my setup at iTunesConnect:
[image]

Now my developer can't able to access my created application within the Xcode to create a build.
This is the problem, he was getting.
[image]

For an Individual account type, is it possible to give authority to create build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You need an organization account to have multiple team members who can build and test the app on devices.

Apple has outsourced the definition of "organization" to Dun & Bradstreet. They issue D-U-N-S numbers. You need to form a company, nonprofit, or governmental organization recognized by D&B so that they will issue you this D-U-N-S number. How to do this will vary by where you live and where your organization will be legally located. You can then either create a new account or transform your current account into an organization account.

Then you can add additional team members to your account, giving these other team members varying levels of access to build and publish apps under that organization.

See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/) for further details.